# Lift error-check multiple form fields

Tags: scala, lift

I'm following a tutorial on how to validate [form fields](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.5.html#prev), but it only demonstrates it for one field. How can I validate, and display errors for multiple fields?

I tried the following - but it always succeeds and does a redirect - no matter the errors:

```
def process() = {
    if (patientName == "Joe") {
      S.error("patientName", "Joe not allowed!")
    }
    if (birthdate == "22/22/2222") {
      S.error("birthdate", "Invalid date!")
    }
    S.notice("Success! You entered Patient name: " + patientName); S.redirectTo("/")    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I figured it out. Beautiful.

```
 def process() = {
    if (patientName == "Joe") {
      S.error("Joe not allowed!")
    }
    if (birthdate == "22/22/2222") {
      S.error("birthdate", "Invalid birthdate!")
    }

    S.errors match {
        case Nil =>S.notice("Patient name: " + patientName); S.redirectTo("/")
        case _ =>
    }
  }
```